# How does keyof keyword works in the specific example

Tags: typescript

I have the following type:

```
export type ActionsMap = {
  add: Function;
  remove: Function;
};
```

Then I have the following type that will map into actions that can be performed in a reducer in React:

```
export type Actions = {
  [Key in keyof ActionsMap]: {
    type: Key;
    payload: ActionsMap[Key];
  };
}[keyof ActionsMap];
```

I'm having issues understanding the `[keyof ActionsMap]`. Going each step I can see that

```
{
  [Key in keyof ActionsMap]: {
    type: Key;
    payload: ActionsMap[Key];
  };
}
```

Will loop over the keys in `ActionsMap` and transform this into a new type:

```
{
  add: {
    type: "add",
    payload: Function
  },
  remove: {
    type: "remove",
    payload: Function
  },
}
```

But how does exactly the last part (`[keyof ActionsMap]`) transforms the previous object into:

```
{ type: "add", payload: Function }
| { type: "remove", payload: Function }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an object-like type `T` and a key-like type `K` that is constrained to `keyof T`, then `T[K]` is an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) corresponding to the property values of `T` at keys of type `K`.  Or, if you have a value `t` of type `T` and a value `k` of type `K`, then the expression `t[k]` has the type `T[K]`.  If `K` is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) like `K1 | K2 | K3` this naturally means that `T[K]` will also be a union type like `T[K1] | T[K2] | T[K3]`.

Using your types as examples, you can observe how this works:

```
type T = {
  add: {
    type: "add",
    payload: Function
  },
  remove: {
    type: "remove",
    payload: Function
  },
}
const t: T = {
  add: { type: "add", payload: () => { } },
  remove: { type: "remove", payload: () => { } }
}

type K = "add" | "remove"
const k: K = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "add" : "remove";

const tk: T[K] = t[k];
/* const tk: {
    type: "add";
    payload: Function;
} | {
    type: "remove";
    payload: Function;
} */
```

Since `k` might be either of the keys of `t`, then `t[k]` might be either of the properties of `t`.  Therefore a union in `K` produces a union in `T[K]`.

---

The specific technique you show, where you take a type function `F<K>` and produce a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over it, into which you immediately index, like `{[P in K]: F<P>}[K]`, called a *distributive object type* as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), is one way to help distribute `F<K>` over unions in `K`.  In your case, `F<K>` is `{type: K, payload: ActionsMap[K]}`, so the type `Actions` just distributes that over the union `keyof ActionsMap` to produce a new union `{type: "add", payload: Function} | {type: "remove", payload: Function}`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDeBYAUFKBDAJjgXMuppqJIQES44UA0xJYWIANgPa6EBiArgHYBjYAEs2fBgF96GKACcIAWzYA3CIVQzS4NVArylqug0xNWHAlF6CRYydInoBYgM7AowQnEQbM1de+1KajooU3ZOKAAKAEoEAD5kKAkk6Ux9FR0kAPJddMNaUOZwixj4xOSHNEr0MmgAaQRdYKgAH1zFDIpHFzcAa0IGxABZLGAACwA6WSw+HDYFUoAeKAAGCYBWKAB+JrwKKEo8iAoAbnRuvld3ftgAbTqAXUbgW96Hs7QAegAqKCdLtzAG4+Ei1IJ7D4kQpmCJWISiPgfZJtEFaHJ6DqGSGMIrmbj8eFiJFQb6fIA)